# How to fix Google Chart that only loads on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, load

My site is built as one page that show and hide sections (pages) with javascript.
Im trying to load 3 Google Charts on my page, but the charts will only load if i go to the page (statistics) and refresh it?

In my html file i call the google js api:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

In my js file i call the google charts before my $(document).ready:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart']});
$(document).ready(function() {
   function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      // Adding data and options to chart1
      var data_2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
      // Adding data and options to chart2
      var data_3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
      // Adding data and options to chart3

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('class_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('column_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data_2, options_2);
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('gender_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data_3, options_3);
   }

   if ($("#pageStatistics']").hasClass('active')) {
      drawChart();
   }

});// document.ready end
```

It all works, but as i wrote, when i go to the statistics page i have to refresh the site before the charts load..?

Answer (score 0):

Why instead of doing that on the document ready you change your code to refresh the charts.
Everytime you open your statistics page.

```
$("#pageStatistics").click(function(){
   drawChart();
})
```

Also if you click on that area of your page and then check if it has the "active" class

Comment: hmm, but this doesnt seem to fix the problem with the refresh?
what do you mean with 'that area of your page'?

Comment: The pageStatistics i understand is some kind of div on you page no? If it is if you open your page and the div is not selected it won't update the charts. And if you want to refresh it again you need to refresh the entire page. This is because the if ($("#pageStatistics']").hasClass('active')) it's only checked once. Well that's what I understood